# Iterative formula for the integration of autonomous differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, approximate-integration

Consider the following autonomous differential equation:

$$y'=f(y)$$

where $y=y(t)$ with  $y_0 = y(0)$.

Let us suppose that $y^{[0]}(t)$ is a good approximation for $y(t)$. Using this function in the right part of the differential equation, we obtain

$$y(t) \approx y_0 + \int\limits_{0}^t f(y^{[0]}(\tau)) {\rm d}\tau \equiv y^{[1]}(t)$$

That is, we arrived at the following iteration formula:

$$y^{[k+1]}(t) = y_0 + \int\limits_{0}^t f(y^{[k]}(\tau)) {\rm d}\tau$$

Should this kind of iteration converge to $y(t)$? If so, then is this an existing method to solve differential equations?

Comment: It usually converges, it is the basis for most of the existence theory, and no, this is not a good numerical method or solution trick. The name is Picard iteration, sometimes with another name (Volterra?) thrown in.